# Electromagnetic Dipole Radiation Derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, dipole, multipole-expansion

I was reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole?oldformat=true#Dipole_radiation) wikepedia page, about the dipole radiation, and I was wondering how to derive the $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ fields in this situation.

I've started using the retarded potentials:
$$
\phi(\mathbf r, t) = \left ( \frac{q}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s|(1-\mathbf{\hat n}\cdot\boldsymbol \beta_s)} \right )_{t_r}\\ \; \\
\mathbf A (\mathbf r, t) = \left (\frac{1}{c}\phi(\mathbf r, t) \boldsymbol \beta_s \right )_{t_r}
$$

Where:
$$
t_r = t - \frac{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s|}{c} \\ \; \\
\mathbf r _s(t_r) \; \; \; \text{trajectorie of the particle} \\ \; \\
\boldsymbol \beta_s = \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \mathbf r _s}{\partial t_r} \\ \; \\
\mathbf {\hat n} = \frac{\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s|}
$$
Expanding $\phi$ in a taylor series for $1/r$. Calling $\mathbf R = \mathbf r - \mathbf r_s$, we have:
$$
\phi(\mathbf r, t) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{|\mathbf R|(1 -\mathbf{\hat n}\cdot\boldsymbol \beta_s)} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 |\mathbf R|} f(\mathbf R, t) \approx\frac{q}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 |\mathbf R|} \Bigg (f(\mathbf 0, t) + \mathbf{\hat n} \cdot \nabla_\mathbf{R} f(\mathbf 0, t) + \mathcal O(|\mathbf R|^2)\Bigg) 
$$
I've calculated it to be:
$$
\phi(\mathbf r, t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 |\mathbf R|} \Bigg( 1 + \mathbf{\hat n}\cdot \boldsymbol{\beta}_s \Bigg)
$$
But I don't know if this dipole expansion is valid (or even useful)? Any Hint?

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated than you think. You have to use ${\bf E}=-\nabla\phi-\frac{1}{c}\partial_t{\bf A}$ BEFORE any approximation. With everything at the retarded time, this is a difficult derivation. It is done, at great length, in textbooks.  Wikipedia is convenient to use, but it's hard to learn from.